# PySimpleGui Output Title Bar Name Problem

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pysimplegui

I want to print an output something like this by using pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
print("The age of the universe is", age_of_universe, "Gyr")
print("The age of universe at z = ", z, "is", age_of_universe_at_z,)
print("Lookback time is", lookback_time , "Gyr")
print("Comoving distance to an object at z =", z , "is" , comoving_distance, "Mpc")
print("Luminosity distance to an object at z =", z, "is", luminosity_distance, "Mpc")
print("Angular diameter distance to an object at z =", z, "is", angular_distance, "Mpc")
```

I tried to use the popup method. However this time the thing that written inside the popup becomes the name of the title bar

```
sg.popup('This is the modified LightGreen3 Theme', 'It has black button text')
```

[image]

So how can I print these things and can name the title bar whatever I want.

Thanks.

Note: I can accept solutions offered by using tkinter but I prefer pysimpleguı

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PySimpleGUI the parameter to look for when you want to set the titlebar text is `title`.  All of the popups have a title parameter like the `Window` object does.

This popup window has a title:

[image]

the code used to make it is:

```
sg.popup('This is a popup.....Make sure it is long enough to see title.', title='My own title')
```

You can find a description of the popup parameters in the main documentation, http://www.PySimpleGUI.org.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I also have one more question

Comment: In the code that I am sahred there are some variable in the print statement, which seperated by the commas. So when put it in the popup. Everytime it seems a comma it begins a new line. However I need those varible names to shown on the GUI so how can I solve that problem ?

Comment: Once you exceed the capabilities of the popup function, you create your own window where you can control everything including newlines.  Popup is a convenience kind of function that works at a high level.  Sounds like you need to create a custom window that works the way you want.

Comment: There is also a Print function that outputs to a scrolling "debug window".  This acts more like a traditional print function.  It too is a high-level function that can be recreated by users if it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Maybe I should open another question for that. I am not sure how to create such window... Is it written in the document that you shared ?

Comment: In short, yes, the documentation has everything you need including links to other documents and sample code.  You'll need to spend a little time learning this GUI SDK like any other GUI package. But instead of days it'll be hours most likely.